# How to remove the ticklabels from a seaborn.objects plot

Tags: python, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

How to disable the axes' ticklabels for seaborn.objects generated image?

```
import seaborn as sns
from seaborn import objects as so

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
(
    so.Plot(tips, "total_bill", "tip")
    .add(so.Dots())
    .layout(size=(4, 5))
    .label(x=None, y=None)
    .save("data/dot_01.png")
    .show()
)
```

The above code generated image still includes the ticklabels (in red boxes):
[image]

How to disable the ticklabels so that the image could be something like the below one without any blank gaps around the four edges, i.e., the grey background edges are the images' edges:
[image]

Comment: See [Anatomy of a figure](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/showcase/anatomy.html). There are no ticks on the image, so the question is confusing.

Comment: See [Theme customization](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html#theme-customization) and [`seaborn.objects.Plot.theme`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Plot.theme.html#seaborn.objects.Plot.theme)

Comment: `.theme({'grid.color': 'gainsboro', 'axes.facecolor': 'gainsboro'})` will make the facecolor and grid color the same. `.theme({'axes.grid': False})` will remove the grid.

Comment: See [Customizing Matplotlib with style sheets and rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) for the options that can be sent to `.theme`. [Customizing limits, labels, and titles](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html#customizing-limits-labels-and-titles). `.label(x='', y='')` changes / removes the x and y label

Comment: I'm providing a comment instead of an answer, because it's not clear what you really want. As your plot has no ticks and no labels.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thanks for your comments and suggestions, I have updated the question, but I cannot see a way to remove the ticks currently.

Comment: You can check [example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html#customizing-legends-and-ticks) and [Continous.tick](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Continuous.html#seaborn.objects.Continuous.tick) specifying None explicitly would help I guess.

Comment: @GodWin tried adding `.scale(x=so.Continuous().tick(every=None), y=so.Continuous().label(like=None))` but still not working, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedFormatter

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
empty_formatter = FixedFormatter([])

(
    so.Plot(tips, "total_bill", "tip")
    .add(so.Dots())
    .layout(size=(4, 5))
    .label(x=None, y=None)
    .scale(
           x=so.Continuous().tick().label(formatter = empty_formatter),
           y=so.Continuous().tick().label(formatter = empty_formatter)
           )
    .save("dot_01.png")
    .show()
)
```

Will generate the plot which looks closest to your example.

[image]

Comment: thanks, it's very close to the effect I want, except there are some blank gaps around the image's four edges, wonder if these gaps could be removed too?

Comment: @J.W If you're not going to have ticks or ticklabels, there's no point having a grid. So use `.theme({'axes.facecolor': 'w', 'axes.grid': False})` and then you can't tell there is padding around the image. Incidentally, I can't find any command in [Customizing Matplotlib with style sheets and rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) to remove the padding.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney The reason I want to remove the padding/labels/ticklabels is that I want to overlap the generated image (after make it a bit transparent) on top of the other image with the same image size, with the padding will make the two image at different scale so they are not well overlapped. But good to know currently removing padding might not supported, I will try other ways to remove the padding like use PIL to edit the image.

Comment: @J.W The `so` interface is relatively new and I don't know all of its features. However, `sns.scatterplot` is an `axes` level plot, and you can plot multiple plots onto the same axes. (e.g. `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))` then `sns.scatterplot(..., ax=ax)` and `sns.scatterplot(..., ax=ax)`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thank you so much for mentioning `sns.scatterplot`, it can generate the above image without padding by using `ax.set(xlabel=None)` `ax.set(ylabel=None)` `ax.set(xticklabels=[])` `ax.set(yticklabels=[])`, and at the same time overlaps another plot from `sns.kdeplot`, it's perfect for me :)

Comment: @J.W the commands can be consolidated into `ax.set(xlabel=None, ylabel=None, xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[])`